# MLA sequential quotes on same page

Tags: formatting, mla

I have a piece of text in an essay where I'm quoting different pieces of a paragraph found on the same page. I'm not sure how to cite this. [This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/9693/multiple-same-source-citations-in-the-same-paragraph-in-mla-format) shows how to cite if there are different pages, but if they are on the same page, do I just mark the same page again?

For example, is this correct?

> Mrs. Miller lives a lonely life, having “no friends to speak of”
>   (Capote 2), “narrow” (2) interests and rarely travelling “farther than
>   the corner grocery” (2).

If not, what's the alternative? Am I not supposed to have this scenario in the first place? I assumed it was acceptable, since I'm imitating the style I found [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://journals.hil.unb.ca/index.php/IFR/article/download/13422/14505).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to page two of [this guide](http://ithacalibrary.com/research/mla_parenthetical.pdf), it is acceptable to put the references at the end.

Using my previous example.

> Mrs. Miller lives a lonely life, having “no friends to speak of”
>   , “narrow” interests and rarely travelling “farther than
>   the corner grocery” (Capote 2).